# קָמָץ vs. קָמַץ in Ashkenazi pronunciation

Tags: hebrew, ashkenazi, pronunciation, nusach-ashkenaz

All Ashkenazi readers/minhagim/etc. I've seen call this vowel קָמַץ, while there is considerable variation on whether the second syllables of the other vowel names (except for סֶגּוֹל, though there is some variation in spelling there; שְׁוָא, though it is sometimes spelled חוֹלָם ;שְׁבָא; and חֲטָף) receive a long or short vowel. While I've seen people transliterate *komots*/*komotz*, and even *kumutz* with the Yeshivish "uh" pronunciation, I wonder if any Ashkenazim actually write קָמָץ (and actually do say *komots*).

Comment: Is this on topic? I think the original name was kametz with a tzere

Comment: It was indeed kametz with a tzere. I don't know if this is on topic, but I've asked elsewhere and not gotten a response, and there's no Hebrew SE.